# python - Split a string in a CSV file by delimiter

Tags: python, file, csv, split

I have a CSV file with the following data:

```
Date,Profit/Losses
Jan-10,867884
Feb-10,984655
Mar-10,322013
Apr-10,-69417
May-10,310503
Jun-10,522857
Jul-10,1033096
Aug-10,604885
Sep-10,-216386
Oct-10,477532
Nov-10,893810
Dec-10,-80353
```

I have imported the file in python like so:

```
with open(csvpath, 'r', errors='ignore') as fileHandle:
lines = fileHandle.read()
```

I need to loop through these lines such that I extract just the months i.e. "Jan", "Feb", etc. and put it in a different list. I also have to somehow skip the first line i.e. `Date, Profit/Losses` which is the header.

Here's the code I wrote I so far:

```
months = []
for line in lines:
    months.append(line.split("-")
```

When I try to print the `months` list though, it splits every single character in the file!! 
Where am I going wrong here??

Comment: The `csv` module is your friend. Alternatively `pandas` would be a huge help.

Comment: When you read the whole file with `read`, you do not have lines anymore. Your `lines` is one string and `for line in lines` goes over individual letters. See a proposed solution below.

Comment: @DYZ, that makes a whole lotta sense! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can almost always minimize the pain by using specialized tools, such as the `csv` module and list comprehension:

```
import csv
with open("yourfile.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile) # Create a new reader
    next(reader) # Skip the first row
    months = [row[0].split("-")[0] for row in reader]
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use a `DictReader()`, e.g. `reader = csv.DictReader(infile); months = [row['Date'].split('-')[0] for row in reader]`, not much different other than it handles the column header for you.

Answer (score 1):

One answer to your question is to use `fileHandle.readlines()`.

```
lines = fileHandle.readlines()
# print(lines)
# ['Date,Profit/Losses\n', 'Jan-10,867884\n', 'Feb-10,984655\n', 'Mar-10,322013\n',
#  'Apr-10,-69417\n', 'May-10,310503\n', 'Jun-10,522857\n', 'Jul-10,1033096\n', 'Aug-10,604885\n',
#  'Sep-10,-216386\n', 'Oct-10,477532\n', 'Nov-10,893810\n', 'Dec-10,-80353\n']

for line in lines[1:]:
    # Starting from 2nd item in the list since you just want months
    months.append(line.split("-")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you really want to do it the hard way:

```
months = []
for line in lines[1:]:
    months.append(line.split("-")[0])
```

`lines[1:]` will skip the first row and `line.split("-")[0]` will only pull out the month and append to your list `months`.

However, as suggested by AChampion, you should really look into the `csv` or `pandas` packages.

Comment: Tried this, it doesn't work! It endlessly prints each letter in the whole file and doesn't stop. I had to Ctrl + C to interrupt the terminal.

Comment: Oh, try `lines = fileHandle.readlines()`; that will make sure that each row of your table is read in separately

Answer (score 0):

This should deliver desired results (assuming that file named data.csv in same directory):

```
result = []

with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as data:
    next(data)
    for record in data:
        result.append(record.split('-')[0])
```