# REGEX for complex strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the lines from a CSV file:

1. **315,"Misérables, Les (1995)",Drama|War**
2. **315,Big Bully (1996),Comedy|Drama**

I want to split the line and make a list of 3 elements and I need a general REGEX expression that splits where it encounters ',' but since the title may have a comma (As shown in the first line), I need to skip the parsing of the title. A title that has commas has also quotation marks but I need the expression to work for both cases. Is it possible doing it with REGEX?

I'm trying to learn REGEX by myself and I'm having difficulties understanding some cases. I could really appreciate your help!

Comment: by parenthesis do you mean quotation marks? `""`?  If so, you can first try to split the string by them, if you get 3 items, you are done, if not,  split by comma

Comment: Python already has a module for CSV parsing, don't try reinventing it with regex.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546368/python-split-a-string-in-a-csv-file-by-delimiter

Comment: It's not that I'm trying to reinvent it, I'm currently trying to define MapReduce jobs and for that I must use REGEX in order to keep the operations as simple as possible. I don't read the file from the main but instead I feed it to STDIN on the terminal while running the python script.

Comment: Why do you redirect the output? Sounds like loading it from file with extra steps

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh What do you mean by 'redirect the output'? I'm currently using MRJob and that's how I learned it, is there some other way?

Comment: and this sounds like a whole new question, where you should include a little more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to parse a `.csv` file, don't do it by hand, Python already has loads of libraries that will do it for you.

Otherwise if your string has quotation marks when there is a comma inside the title, and doesn't have them when there is not, you can do it like this:

```
>>> x = '315,"Misérables, Les (1995)",Drama|War'
>>> y = '315,Big Bully (1996),Comedy|Drama'
>>> x
'315,"Misérables, Les (1995)",Drama|War'
>>> y
'315,Big Bully (1996),Comedy|Drama'

>>> x.split('"') if len(x.split('"')) == 3 else x.split(',')
['315,', 'Misérables, Les (1995)', ',Drama|War']
>>> y.split('"') if len(y.split('"')) == 3 else y.split(',')
['315', 'Big Bully (1996)', 'Comedy|Drama']
```

This leaves the comma inside the first and last part (if it's split by a quotation mark), so you will have to remove them afterwards manually.

Comment: Still on the first line the commas stay inside the split elements, I have to avoid it so the output is the same as the second line.

Comment: that's why I said that it keeps them there, so you need to clean it up afterwards. If you only have 3 columns, it's easy , just remove commas from first and last part. I just wasn't sure if you could have more columns, with more titles, so I didn't want to make unnecessary generic solution for a problem that doesn't require it

Comment: Yes actually, I managed to make it work without feeding it to the STDIN but from code. Thank you it was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not need to use REGEX for this problem. QUOTING will solve this.

For example:

`filereader = csv.reader(csv_input_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')`

give it a try to solve your problem